# How to set the cursor of a new line to the beginning of the line in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, newline, indentation, key-bindings

In emacs Text mode, every time I pressed `enter` key, the cursor will jump to next tab position of the new line, rather the beginning of the new line.
For example, if I enter `line1`, `enter`, `line2`:
`line1
     line2`
The desired format is:
`line1
 line2`

Here is my configuration for text mode:
`(defun my-custom-settings-fn ()
  (setq indent-tabs-mode t)
  (setq tab-stop-list (number-sequence 0 200 4))
  (setq tab-width 4)
  (setq indent-line-function 'insert-tab))
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'my-custom-settings-fn)`

Comment: What major-mode are you using where you wish to change the default behavior?  `M-x describe-mode`

Comment: @lawlist Text mode

Comment: In the latest version of Emacs, i.e., Emacs 25, `text-mode` does not behave like this with no user-configuration.  Try starting Emacs with no user-configuration -- i.e., `emacs -q` -- and verify that behavior you desire is available by default.  Then recursively bisect your user-configuration and find out where it is that you have altered the default behavior.

Comment: Turn off `electric-indent-mode`. Put this in your init file: `(when (fboundp 'electric-indent-mode) (electric-indent-mode -1))`.